# Where to find python fabric setup examples?

Tags: web-server, python, deployment, fabric

I want to know what is your experience with fabric scripts? Do think it is useful?
is there sample scripts for this? copying, setup service etc

I know there is puppet and chef but i am looking for something that does not use a client/server setup to deploy, setup servers etc

your thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These guys are doing a project on fabric and I found some nice stuff there. Their [blog](http://awaseconfigurations.wordpress.com/) and [github](https://github.com/AwaseConfigurations/main). There's lots of simple fabric examples in their fabfile that you might find useful.

Answer (score 2):

I found a lot of examples on the [github's gist](https://gist.github.com) using search.

Comment: Thank you I found many examples to look at. But still very complicated examples.
Was hoping for some more basic day to day stuff.